# Maximize array sum

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

Suppose I have given an integer array of size n.It is given that we can multiply the value of (i)th and (i+1)the elements by -1 in one Operation.we can perform this Operation as many times as we want. Our goal is to maximize the sum of the eintire array . And print that sum.

Constraints:

2<=n<=10^5

-10^9 <=a(i) <= 10^9

My code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n,a,i;
cin >> n;
vector<int>v1;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin >> a;
    v1.push_back(a);
}

for(i=0;i<n-1;)
{
    if(v1[i]<0 && v1[i+1]<0)
    {
        v1[i]=v1[i]*(-1);
        v1[i+1]=v1[i+1]*(-1);
        i=i+2;
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
}
long long int sum=0;

for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
{
    if(v1[i]<0 && abs(v1[i])>abs(v1[i+1]))
    {
        v1[i]=v1[i]*(-1);
        v1[i+1]=v1[i+1]*(-1);
    }
}

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  //  cout <<v1[i] << " ";
}

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    sum=sum+v1[i];
}
  cout << sum;
}
```

My code is accepted for some of the test cases. Can anyone please help me to find out the proper logic for this question?

Answer (score 0):

Well just consider all cases:

- Case `++` --> we get `--`
- Case `--` --> we get `++`
- Case `-+` --> we get `+-`
- Case `+-` --> we get `-+`

And we can notice that If we try to make all elements positive we will end up with at most one negative element.

Also by cases 3 & 4 we can see that we can decide which element (if any) will be negative in the end.

So result is just sum of absolutes values of the array minus smallest absolute value in the array (if amount of negative elements initially is odd)

Comment: Suppose I have array as -10 -4 -5 2 -31.Can u please explain your logic on the given array?

Comment: What to do if amount of negative elements initially is even?

Comment: Try making everything positive, if last element is negate after that just push it to the min absolute value. In this case `-10 -4 -5 2 -31` --> `10 4 -5 2 -31` --> `10 4 5 -2 -31` --> `10 4 5 2 31`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand that in this competitive question stuff, you can never learn C++. On the contrary, your C++ will get worse.

Next, in all this questions, the authors give you already a strong hint by supplying huge numbers in the constraints. This is a strong message. Do not start coding using a brute force approach. Come up with a smart solution.

At first think, then think again and then make a final thinking and develop a good algorithm.

The task is, to make as many as possible values positive.

With the problem at hand, you will see that you can shift the negative sign by applying the given operation to wherever you want. Example: Let the letters be positive integers. Then you can transmorph:

```
 a -b  c  d   to   
-a  b  c  d   or to
 a  b -c  d   or to
 a  b -c  d and then a  b  c  -d
```

that should be understood.

If you have an even number of negatives, you can elimite 2 of them, by shifting the negative sign beneath another negative and then make both values positive. This mechanism is also valid for more negative even numbers in an array.

1st conclusion: an array with an even number of negatives is the same as an array with all numbers beeing positive. We can sum up all absolute values and have the result.

If we have an odd number of negatives, we can shift the sign to wherever we want and can elimiate all but on negative value. Because the sum must be maximun, the negative value need to be minimum, because it will be subtratced. So first, we elimiate as much as possible negatives and then we shift the negative sign to the smallest absolute value.

Now we think further:

We need to find out the count of negative values. If it is even, we can simply add the absolute value of all values and have the result. For odd values, we need to find the smallest absolute value and subtract that.

We could have the idea, to read all values in an `std::vector` then count, the calculate and so on and so on. But not needed. We can do this already during reading the input. We check the so far smallest value and see, if the overall count of negatives is odd or even. We sum all absolute values during reading. If we know at the end, the the number is odd, then we subtract the smallest number twice (because we added it already).

The program could then look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>

int main() {

    // Get the number of test values
    size_t numberOfTestValues{};
    std::cin >> numberOfTestValues;

    // Here we will indicate, if the number of negatives is odd or even
    bool oddNumberOfSignedValues{ false };

    // This will be the result, the running sum
    long sum{};

    // This is the smallest value given
    long smallestValue{std::numeric_limits<long>::max()};

    // Read as many values as specified
    for (size_t i{}; i < numberOfTestValues; ++i) {

        // Read the vale
        long value{};
        std::cin >> value;

        // Check, if we have now, at this moment, an odd or even number of negatives
        if (value < 0)  oddNumberOfSignedValues = not oddNumberOfSignedValues;

        value = std::abs(value);
        // Check for a new smallest value
        if (value < smallestValue) smallestValue = value;

        // Accumulate
        sum += value;
    }
    // In case necessary (count of negatives was odd) subtract smallest number
    if (oddNumberOfSignedValues) sum = sum - smallestValue - smallestValue;

    // Show result to use
    std::cout << sum << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

This will result in minimum complexity.